# Tabletop inlay design sources

Tags: design, router, tabletop

I am planning in making a tabletop, with rounded corners, and want to decorate the top with some grooves that I could make with the router using the edge guide.

Something like this (excuse my drawing skills):

[image]

Apart from this model with three rectangular-shaped grooves that I quickly thought out, are there sites/sources of ideas/plans, ready made?

Actually I don't know what keywords to use to search for this kind of technique and designs. Help on technical taxonomy is welcome.

L.E.: Thanks to mmathis, I updated the question title, "inlay" being the design that I am looking for

Comment: The term you're looking for is "inlay", which you can put into your favorite search engine to find plans. Note that inlays are grooves cut into the wood and filled with another (usually contrasting) wood - leaving the grooves open on a tabletop is a recipe for dirt and grime to collect.

Comment: VTC as a shopping question

Comment: Just to add to what mmathis said, the grooves can also be filled with resin or epoxy, coloured or filled. But of course they can be left open if that's the look you want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does pertain to woodworking, but is a general design question. It can be turned into a good question about technique, but until the OP decides what he wants to do, the question cannot be salvaged

Comment: I don't know of a single resource for this, but try checking Pinterest for "stringing" and "banding" and "inlay".

Comment: @CharlieKilian:  Thank you, that's what I am doing now. As a matter of fact I was thinking of a "blank" inlaying. By that I mean doing the grooves but not filling it with "other wood", just leave it like that. Or maybe I could make the groove very superficial and stain only the groove. I am shying away from filling with other wood as I see it as a very complex and error prone stage.

Comment: @AndreiRînea Yes, I've left empty grooves in pieces to make them more interesting to look at. Features like this are sometimes called "shadow lines", though that term refers not just to empty grooves, but to any carved or raised feature added to make the piece visually more interesting than a flat space would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about pinterest

https://www.pinterest.ca/search/pins/?q=coffee%20table%20top%20decoration%20router&rs=typed&term_meta[]=coffee%7Ctyped&term_meta[]=table%7Ctyped&term_meta[]=top%7Ctyped&term_meta[]=decoration%7Ctyped&term_meta[]=router%7Ctyped

Spor la lucru!